# AWS MFA policy disables CLI access. How do I go about it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-iam, multi-factor-authentication, identity-management

I am using this policy where MFA is required for all users to login before accessing along with EC2FullAcces and S3FullAccess. However, despite providing these policies and enabling MFA, the policy seems to have no issue with Console, but causes issue from CLI. I have tried to reconfigure in CLI using

> aws configure

but can't seem to resolve. Only disabling the MFA policy below seems to resolve the issue, but don't understand why ? How can I enable MFA for both console and CLI using IAM policy ?

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowViewAccountInfo",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
            "iam:ChangePassword"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowManageOwnVirtualMFADevice",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
            "iam:DeleteVirtualMFADevice"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:mfa/${aws:username}"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowManageOwnUserMFA",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:DeactivateMFADevice",
            "iam:EnableMFADevice",
            "iam:GetUser",
            "iam:ListMFADevices",
            "iam:ResyncMFADevice"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "DenyAllExceptListedIfNoMFA",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "NotAction": [
            "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
            "iam:EnableMFADevice",
            "iam:GetUser",
            "iam:ListMFADevices",
            "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
            "iam:ResyncMFADevice",
            "sts:GetSessionToken",
            "iam:ChangePassword"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "BoolIfExists": {
                "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "false"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Replace yours with the following

```
    {
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowViewAccountInfo",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
            "iam:ChangePassword"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowManageOwnVirtualMFADevice",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
            "iam:DeleteVirtualMFADevice"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:mfa/${aws:username}"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowManageOwnUserMFA",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:DeactivateMFADevice",
            "iam:EnableMFADevice",
            "iam:GetUser",
            "iam:ListMFADevices",
            "iam:ResyncMFADevice"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "DenyAllExceptListedIfNoMFA",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "NotAction": [
            "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
            "iam:EnableMFADevice",
            "iam:GetUser",
            "iam:ListMFADevices",
            "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
            "iam:ResyncMFADevice",
            "sts:GetSessionToken",
            "iam:ChangePassword"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "Bool": {
                "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "false"
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

Remove `IfExists` from the condition. You can read more about this condition [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html#Conditions_IfExists).
I missed the part where you asked

> How can I enable MFA for both console and CLI using IAM policy ?

This won't enable `MFA` for programmatic access.